# ¿Por qué no puedo ver/editar las reglas de bandeja de entrada de mi correo Outlook?

Tags: outlook

Hace un tiempo creé unas "inbox rules" en mi correo electrónico outlook y ahora cuando intento editarlas (options > inbox and sweep rules) me sale el siguiente error:
"There was a problem loading your inbox rules. Please try again or click here to report the problem."

No he podido solucionarlo, entre otras cosas, porque encuentro información al respecto para Microsoft Exchange o cuentas de correo en versión de escritorio.
Yo simplemente accedo a mi correo por medio de la web.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda al respecto!

Comment: Kevin, bienvenido a SOes. Es posible que tu pregunta no corresponda a la tématica del sitio, ya que aunque es una herramienta/servicio, no es algo que se use para desarrollar software. Aun asi, esperaremos a ver que dice la comunidad. Si estas familiarizado con el ingles, puedes preguntar en el [SE de aplicaciones Web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), que me parece lo mas apropiado. Saludos.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias. También dudé de preguntar aquí, me pasaré por el sitio, a ver.